# Avoid hijacking of `M-w` in Magit buffers

Tags: key-bindings, magit

I often want to copy some text out of a Magit-buffer - part of a commit message, part of a diff, whatever.

Annoyingly <kbd>M-w</kbd> in a Magit buffer inserts a sha1 into the kill ring (`magit-copy-buffer-revision`), instead of the text between mark and point.

This is driving me insane.

Is there are configuration option or something to avoid this behaviour?

I am not using active regions (`transient-mark-mode`), which seems to be what Magit was designed with in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After loading magit in my ~/.emacs/init.el, I have added this:

```
(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "M-w") 'kill-ring-save)
```

and I regained a sanity point.

Comment: Because the normal `kill-ring-save` binding is in the global key map, you can set `M-w` to `nil` in `magit-mode-map` so it falls back to normal behavior instead of manually redefining it on `M-w` on the `magit-mode-map`.